# How could I sort data from a file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

So my code is a game wich registers the player's name and score in a .txt file so I was trying to make a new class to sort the scores to make a "Highest Scores" button at the start of the game and display the highest scores and corresponding names next to it.
The register method is basicly something like this:

```
Label text = new Label("How much players will play game with game?");
        TextField input = new TextField();
        Button submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setOnAction(event -> {
            tPlayer = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
            window.close();
        });
```

So the file would look something like this:

```
,Player1,56
,player1,18
,player2,61
,noobMaster69,82
```

And then, there's another class with the read method :

```
try {
            File myObj = new File("Jugador.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                // Im stuck here
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, that's all, I have no idea how to continue, any help will be appreciated.

(Sorry If there's any format mistake or something like that, I am kinda noob here :D).

Comment: Create a class that represents a player, containing name and score. Then do research how to parse that information from a string. Then research how to sort Java objects on different properties. Those are the different tasks you have to learn. Please understand that few people here will want to that work for you. Look at the individual steps, and solve them one by one. And ideally, write small individual test classes for each problem. Solve each thing by its own, and only in the end,when everything works integrate your parts into one program.

Comment: That's what a I asking for, not to somebody to my work. Thanks <3.

Comment: Read in to a list. Provide a comparator to sort to sort the list. Save the sorted list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292544/sorting-a-text-file-in-javafx/59293332#59293332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to create a class to represent a `Score`. Something like:

```
public class Score {

    String player;
    float score;

    public Score(String player, float score) {
        super();
        this.player = player;
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

*Be aware that this is just an example. A good* `Score` *class implementation should not represent the* `Player` *as a String. Make changes accordingly.*

After that, we need to make the `Score` class to implement the `Comparable` interface. This signals that `Score` instances can be compared to other objects; specifically in our case, other objects of the type `Score`.

```
public class Score implements Comparable<Score>{

    String player;
    float score;

    public Score(String player, float score) {
        super();
        this.player = player;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score anotherScore) {
        if(this.score > anotherScore.score) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.score < anotherScore.score) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Implementing the `Comparable` interface requires us to write a `compareTo()` method. This method is supposed to decide which, from 2 instances, is "greater" than the other. You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/java-comparable-interface/). The summary of it:

> Return a positive number if `this` instance is greater than the
>   parameter.
>
> Return a negative number if `this` instance is lesse than the parameter.
>
> Return zero if both are equivalent.

Now back to your code. Inside:

```
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    // Im stuck here
}
```

You should create a `Score` instance and add it to a collection.

```
List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = myReader.nextLine();
    String[] splitLine = line.split(",");
    // line = Player1,56
    // splitLine = ["Player1", "56"]
    Score score = new Score(splitLine[0], Float.parseFloat(splitLine[1]));
    scoreList.add(score);
}
Collections.sort(scoreList); // Sorts in ASCENDING order
Collections.sort(scoreList, Collections.reverseOrder()) // Sorts in DESCENDING order
```

`Collections.sort()` will use the `compareTo()` method that you created inside `Score` to sort the list in ascending order.